# Ruby before Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

How did ruby worked before the development of Rack Web Server Interface?

Specifically for what purpose we are using the Rack Middleware?

Please explain with clear real-time example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rack is only one of a myriad of webserver interfaces. Before there was Rack, you could still use any of the others: CGI, FCGI, SCGI, for example. Or you could plug a Ruby execution engine directly into a webserver using for example mod_ruby, mod_rubinius or Phusion Passenger for Apache. Or you could do it the other way round and plug a webserver into Ruby using Webrick or Mongrel.

Rack is a standardized interface between a webserver and a web application. But it's not the only such interface, there are others, and before there was Rack, people used those.

Comment: Which functionality did the Rack Webserver interface reduced,from the early Ruby Application? And Can I have the sample code for that?

Answer (score 2):

**Rack middleware** is a way to filter a `request` and `response` coming into your application. It's an implementation of the [pipeline design pattern](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/ParallelPatterns/PatternLanguage/AlgorithmStructure/Pipeline.htm) for web servers using [Rack](http://rack.github.io/).

It very cleanly separates out the different stages of processing a request - separation of concerns being a key goal of all well designed software products.

### What's Middleware?

Middleware is a dreadful term which refers to any software component/library which assists with but is not directly involved in the execution of some task. Very common examples are `logging`, `authentication` and the other common, `horizontal processing components`. These tend to be the things that everyone needs across multiple applications but not too many people are interested (or should be) in building themselves.

More Info:

- **RailsCast** : **[Rack Middleware](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware)**
- **[Introduction to Rack middleware](http://www.amberbit.com/blog/introduction-to-rack-middleware)**

Comment: Which functionality did the Rack Webserver interface reduced,from the early Ruby Application? And Can I have the sample code for that? Can I have sample code for those examples that you have mentioned with and without Rack Interface.